# I see 'fffd' in my wordcloud created using tweets of celebrities

Tags: r, character-encoding, text-mining

I was trying to understand what topics do some of the celebritites about. I established a twitter API connection and got tweets of a few personalities from their verified handles.

I processed the tweets by following -

1. Replaced graphic characters by blank
   `AmitText=str_replace_all(tweets.df$text,"[^[:graph:]]", " ")`
2. Converted all characters to lower case
3. Removed punctuations, hyperlinks, tabs, Keyword "rt" and blankspaces at the begining and end of tweets
4. Created corpus, removed stopwords and created a wordcloud
   `AmitText.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(AmitText))`
   `AmitText.corpus <- tm_map(AmitText.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("en"))`
   `wordcloud(AmitText.corpus,min.freq = 2, scale=c(7,0.5),colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"),random.color= FALSE, random.order = FALSE, max.words = 150)`

This creates a decent wordcloud, but the problem is, I get a big 'fffd' in the middle of the wordcloud, suggesting that this is the word tweeted by the celeb the most. In fact, this is the pattern I see for all the 7 celebrities. Although I was sure this cannot be the case, I checked their raw tweets too, and found no such word as fffd in their tweets. From what I understand, this is some graphic character that isn't getting read correctly. I am not sure what is the reason and google isn't of much help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this in the beginning of your data pre-processing.

```
iconv(tweet$text, from="UTF-8", to="ASCII", sub="")
```

Hope this helps!

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Comment: "ashokmistry4545 pride of india ����srbachchan many congratulations sir ab28million"  I still see this as one of the tweets text. Do you think characters like � are getting read as fffd ?

Comment: to remove these junk values why don't use `tweet$text <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]///' ]", "", tweet$text)`. BTW - yes, this is the cause of fffd when you do tolower() - refer this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

They are **not junk** characters. They are designed to tell you *and your users* that somewhere **data was lost** due to **mishandling** of *their* text.

There is a big difference between "Please pay �1000" and "Please pay 1000" when the original is "Please pay ₹1000"—or was it "Please pay ₿1000"? Removing � is not an ideal solution.

Somewhere some program read a text file or stream using a character encoding other than the one it was written or sent with. Simple as that. Hopefully, you can fix it upstream.

Comment: Oh, � and [U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) are the same thing.

Comment: � denotes anything that is unreadable by the UTF format and is replaced by U+FFFD. This is why, in the wordcloud, I see fffd as the word with maximum frequency

Comment: Well, certainly it wasn't written with the intention that it be unreadable. Find the buggy code that is misreading it.